# What is it the executive command put between double slashes for in perl?

Tags: perl, syntax

I'm trying to build gccg(gccg.sourceforge.net) on my mac pro with mountain lion installed.
I've tried to install every things according to the manual, but it gave me some error like:

> gccg_package.pl: gccg_package requires gunzip at gccg_package.pl line 1224.

Then I'm trying to root this problem, and recursively find the root of this:

```
($_ = `gunzip --version 2>&1`)  &&  /gunzip / or die "$0: gccg_package requires gunzip";
```

I output the each part of the operands with this && operators, and make sure that "/gunzip /" returns false here. The problem here is that I don't what does those statements mean here?

Sorry for my newbie with perl, I've tried to find some tutorial but seems it's not so easy to search anyway.

Comment: I would expect this statement to perform simple pattern matching. So `/gunzip /` is equivalent to `($_ =~ /gunzip /)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit rusty in perl but:

the first part `` ($_ = `gunzip --version 2>&1`) `` executes `gunzip --version 2>&1` and stores the output in `$_`

the `&&` is used as a short cut operated, if the left hand side returns true the right hand side will be executed.

the right hand side `/gunzip /` is a regular expression, in perl if there is no variable (scalar)
declared for an regex it will be performed on the default variable `$_`
So this will just search the oputput of the first part for "gunzip " and return true if it contains it

The last part `or die "$0: gccg_package requires gunzip";` will only be executed if one of the 2 previous parts returned false.

for more information on Short Circuit operations check out http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355

Comment: +1 for the mention of an regex without variable(scalar) declared will be performed on the default variable $_

Answer (score 4):

In short, it causes the program to end if the output of `gunzip --version 2>&1` doesn't include the string `gunzip`.

- `` $_ =  `gunzip --version 2>&1` `` executes the shell command in the backticks, captures its output, stores the output in `$_`, and returns true if output was returned.
- `/gunzip /` is a match operator. It returns true if content of `$_` contains the string `gunzip`.
- `die` throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this line tells you that you should install `gunzip`.

`gunzip` is a Unix command ; what this lines does is that it first assigns to the variable `$_` the result of the `gunzip --version` part ; then it runs the regular expression search `/gunzip /` on that variable, to check that the result of the command contains `gunzip` (as opposed to `gunzip`, without a space, which would also be found if the command's result was `gunzip: command not found`). And finally, if the search is not successful, e.g. `gunzip` was not executed for one reason or the other, the program stops (`die`) after printing the message that you read.